# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jadira/usertype/spi/shared/AbstractSingleColumnUserType

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime, usertype

I am using some classes from the UserType Library but I am getting some errors. Seems like there are some classes missing like for this error.

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jadira/usertype/spi/shared/AbstractSingleColumnUserType

Please guide me about what to do. First in the start i had downloaded 3.2.0 version, but I downgraded to 3.0.0 CR1 but still I am getting some class not found excecptions.

Please help. This thing itself is taking much time...

I am using Usertype like this...

```
package classes.mastertables;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate;


@Entity
public class BranchMaster {

private String companyId;
@Id
private String branchId;
@Column(unique=true)
private String branchNm;
private String branchOfficeAddress;
@Column(unique=true)
private long branchOfficeTel;
@Column(unique=true)
private long branchOfficeFax;
private String branchOfficeCity;
private String branchOfficeStateCode;
private String branchOfficeCountryCode;
private String branchTypeId;
private String parentBranchId;
private Boolean activeFlg;
private Boolean isBranchOnline;
private String createdBy;
@Column 
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
private PersistentLocalDate createdDt;//modified to String
private String modifiedBy;
@Column 
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
private PersistentLocalDate modifiedDt;//modified to String
private String dateFormat;
//Getters and settters follow
```

In Hibernate.cfg.xml i am adding these 2 lines

```
<mapping class="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate" />
    <mapping class="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime" />
```

Please guide...

Thanks,
Abhijeet.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the jar containing class : `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException` which is refered in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Generally java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError occurs when a your code refers a jar -> which intern refers another jar -> and that other jar is missing in your case.

Comment: I do not think this is the problem...Right now I added 2 jars usertypeSpi 3.2.0 GA and core 3.2.0Ga and now I am getting this error..java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator not a subtype

Comment: Well, I answered to NCDef error... Good to know you have resolved it